# Como enviar a imagem selecionada com javascript?

Tags: javascript, imagem, viewport

Estou adaptando meu blog para ser responsivo. Porém, ao ocultar o banner, ele ainda continua lá e carregado sempre acesso a página. Gostaria de saber se é possível carregar imagens de acordo com a resolução da *viewport*. Não sei se é possível, mas o meu objetivo é descobrir a largura da *viewport* através do javascript e para aquela resolução enviar o link da imagem apropriada, sem precisar usar jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é bem o que precisas, mas dá uma olhada nisto
http://adaptive-images.com

Já existe à algum tempo, basicamente, o browser comunica com o PHP através de uma COOKIE, que é criada na primeira utilização e nas próximas iterações com o site o PHP irá criar imagens para os tamanhos especificados.

Comment: Então, o problema é que a plataforma que estou utilizando é Blogger e eu não sei se suporta PHP.

Comment: Nunca usei Blogger, penso que não será possível tanta customização..